# Cannot load the data from the Gsheet in real phone

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-sheets, gsheets

I make some android app that can input data and store it in Google sheets When I run it in the emulator, it work really well. I can input new data and it show the data in the sheets. But, when I compile it and install in my real phone, the data wont show and I can't input new data. It just keep loading. any solution?

I tried to change the Kotlin, the Gradle. But it wont change anything. the app still loading and wont load the data from the sheets to real phone

```
import 'package:gsheets/gsheets.dart';

class GoogleSheetsApi {
  // create credentials
  static const _credentials = r'''
  {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "fortunaapp1",
  "private_key_id": "50d7c550a7125c82dc99e3481f3441d8453bec68",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\naMmn/UhoRJertqcGpN7GTIQh\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "fortuna@fortunaapp1.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "118121372819582547029",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/fortuna%40fortunaapp1.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
  ''';

  // set up & connect to the spreadsheet
  static final _spreadsheetId = '1_om4BImQtpn3SjehwztKosEvmHQx9cRHQRrZeJkWKfY';
  static final _gsheets = GSheets(_credentials);
  static Worksheet? _worksheet;

  // some variables to keep track of..
  static int numberOfTransactions = 0;
  static List<List<dynamic>> currentTransactions = [];
  static bool loading = true;

  // initialise the spreadsheet!
  Future init() async {
    final ss = await _gsheets.spreadsheet(_spreadsheetId);
    _worksheet = ss.worksheetByTitle('Sheet1');
    countRows();
  }

  // count the number of notes
  static Future countRows() async {
    while ((await _worksheet!.values
            .value(column: 1, row: numberOfTransactions + 1)) !=
        '') {
      numberOfTransactions++;
    }
    // now we know how many notes to load, now let's load them!
    loadTransactions();
  }

  // load existing notes from the spreadsheet
  static Future loadTransactions() async {
    if (_worksheet == null) return;

    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfTransactions; i++) {
      final String dataNama =
          await _worksheet!.values.value(column: 1, row: i + 1);
      final String dataPaspor =
          await _worksheet!.values.value(column: 2, row: i + 1);
      final String dataSponsor =
          await _worksheet!.values.value(column: 3, row: i + 1);
      final String dataTanggal =
          await _worksheet!.values.value(column: 4, row: i + 1);

      if (currentTransactions.length < numberOfTransactions) {
        currentTransactions.add([
          dataNama,
          dataPaspor,
          dataSponsor,
          dataTanggal,
        ]);
      }
    }
    print(currentTransactions);
    // this will stop the circular loading indicator
    loading = false;
  }

  // insert a new transaction
  static Future insert(
      String nama, String paspor, String sponsor, String tanggal) async {
    if (_worksheet == null) return;
    numberOfTransactions++;
    currentTransactions.add([
      nama,
      paspor,
      sponsor,
      tanggal,
    ]);
    await _worksheet!.values.appendRow([
      nama,
      paspor,
      sponsor,
      tanggal,
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have some error? post code.

Comment: there is no error in my code. everything just work perfectly fine